# Upper bound for $f(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I just need to know if my solution to the following problem is correct.

> Find an upper bound for $|z^3-2z^2+5z-4|$, if $z$ is inside the circle centered at the origin with radius 2.

My solution: $|z|<2$.

$|z^3-2z^2+5z-4|\le|z^3|+|2z^2|+|5z|+|4|<8+8+10+4=30$

My questions: Is it right that $|z|<2$ or should it be $|z|\le2$? Also, I'm a bit unsure of the minus signs. Could I have gotten a lower-valued upper bound? Thanks.

Comment: A circle $S^1 = \{ z : e^{iz} = 1 \}.$ Inside the circle might mean the unit disk...

Answer (score 1):

Since $z^3-2z^2+5z-4$ is a polynomial, it is entire and it is bounded on the closed disk $|z|\leq 2$. Thanks to the maximum modulus theorem $|z^3-2z^2+5z-4|$ achieves its maximum on $|z|=2$. And when you plug $z=-2$ the value of the norm is $30$. So, it looks like your upper bound is the best you can get.

Inside the circle might mean $|z|<2$. I would define the case $|z|\leq 2$ as "inside the closed circle". I am not sure though. However your answer is $|f(z)|<30$ or $|f(z)|\leq 30$ for either case.

Comment: Very precise answer (+1). One detail : in my opinion, adjective "bounded" is preferable to "finite".

Comment: @JeanMarie, you are right. I have edited.